# SystemVerilog/Verilator WIDTH parameter and case structure indexing out of bounds

Tags: system-verilog, verilator

I'm currently implementing a PRNG in SystemVerilog using an LFSR as described [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf). The width should be variable using a parameter. I reach a construct of:

```
module PRNG
#(
    parameter WIDTH = 32,
    parameter SEED = 1
)
(
    input clk,
    input update,
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] prng
);

reg [WIDTH-1:0] lastRng = WIDTH'(SEED);

always_comb begin
    var tap;

    case (WIDTH)
        default: tap = 0;
        3: tap = lastRng[2] ^~ lastRng[1];
        [...]
        168: tap = lastRng[167] ^~ lastRng[165] ^~ lastRng[152] ^~ lastRng[150];
    endcase

    if (update) begin
        prng = {lastRng[WIDTH-2:0], tap};
    end else begin
        prng = lastRng;
    end
end

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    lastRng <= prng;
end

endmodule
```

Now, while simulating this module using Verilator it complains of selection indices out of range for every case `> WIDTH-1`, even though (I think that) these cases should clearly be optimized out, since WIDTH is a constant:

```
Selection index out of range: 167:167 outside 31:0
```

Is there a simple way around this error, without eg. bit shifting logic just to index the nth bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to use a `generate`.

Try this

1. Move the case statement block outside of the `always_comb` (you can't use `generate` in an `always` block, someone correct me if that does not stand for `always_comb`
2. Change the `tap =` statements to be `assign tap =`.
3. (optional) Surround the `case` block with `generate`/`endgenerate`. This isn't required but you might find it helps readability.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restructure your block so you don't have out-of-bound references. In simulation, the compiler is not required to optimize your procedural code based on constant values, so it needs to be legal. Moving the case statement outside the `always` block changes it from procedural to elaboration based (same for `if` and `for`-loop statements.

```
logic tap;// same as var tap, but better to show the implicit data type

case (WIDTH)
    default: assign tap = 0;
    3: assign tap = lastRng[2] ^~ lastRng[1];
    [...]
    168: assign tap = lastRng[167] ^~ lastRng[165] ^~ lastRng[152] ^~ lastRng[150];
endcase

always_comb
if (update)
    prng = {lastRng[WIDTH-2:0], tap};
else 
    prng = lastRng;
```